# How to install software-properties-gtk package in python? on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x

i run this command sudo apt install python3.7.

E: The package libglu1-mesa:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

this error massage still showing.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python3.7-venv python3.7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/528 kB of archives.
After this operation, 439 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python3.7.
(Reading database ... 199040 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3.7_3.7.7-1+bionic1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.7 (3.7.7-1+bionic1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up python3.7 (3.7.7-1+bionic1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libglu1-mesa:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglu1-mesa:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk`

Comment: sudo apt install software-properties-gtk this command not working.

Comment: what error you are getting? what exactly you want? you want to install python3.7 or software-properties-gtk?